# Javascript works on localhost, but it stops on deploy github pages or vercel

Tags: javascript, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages, vercel

Can someone tell me why the javascript works on localhost, but when using github Pages or vercel, the javascript stops?

code on github:https://github.com/Marincor/Bx-Bank

Deploy githubpage: https://marincor.github.io/Bx-Bank/

Deploy on Vercel: https://bx-bank.vercel.app/

when I go to the dev tools source of the pages index.html and cadastro.html they don't have the JS folder that I have linked.

[print of devTools chrome sourcers tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSy4M.png)

[print of github JS folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPMPc.png)

[print of the script src inside the html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnpOp.png)

i don't know what to do, any tips?

for some reason, the home.html works the javascript file, just index.html and cadastro.html doesn't.

Comment: Please do not ask us to debug your github repo. Instead edit the question and add a [mcve] to it.

Comment: Maybe because on GitHub it's case sensitive.

Comment: I added some prints of the case in the question, that can help?

Comment: A screenprint is not a [mcve]. We can't run it, nor can we copy/paste from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the path to your script file with a preceding `./` like you do with your css links:

```
<script type="module" src="./Assets/JS/Index.js"></script>
```

Edit: and be aware of casing:

```
<script type="module" src="./Assets/JS/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: I changed, but nothing of javascript yet

Comment: Oh hey your file is `index.js` lowercase not capitalized.

Comment: changed, but nothing yet. Just on the home.html that javascript works :/. On localhost all files work, i dont get it

Comment: works for me now. with your dev tools open in the browser, ensure disable caching is selected in the network tab and refresh the page. Or if that doesn't make sense, then hold down Ctrl and then press F5 on your keyboard.

Comment: WOOOL, WORKS, THANKS MAN<3

Comment: now the home.html doesn't find the home.js javascript file. G.G you know what could be?

Comment: it might be a problem with `home.html` being appended to the end of the url. check your dev tools to see what path the browser is attempting to get home.js at. Also watch your casing again, firstly. There's a discrepancy in your code between `home.js` and `Home.js`

Comment: I checked, the home.html is appoint to  <script  src="./Assets/JS/home.js"></script> and the file name is home.js (lowercase this time), but doesn't work. in the dev tools of google chrome, the same problem that was with the previous files, of not uploading javascript on deploy. :/

Comment: holy, was the name too. some problem when i commit the Home.js to home.js. xD thank you a lot, Porter!